# Importing and exporting JS libraries

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, import, export

Here I have a set of libs I have defined

lib1.js

```
export default {
    Func1() {
        return ...
    }
}
```

(and so forth for my other libs)

Here I am importing those libs into a main file that I want to import in my Vue later:

api.js (not lib1, lib2, lib3 and api are in the same folder)

```
import './lib1';
import './lib2';
import './lib3';
```

in vue:

```
<script>
    import * as Api from '@/api/api';

    mounted() {
      Api.func1();
    }

</script>
```

Mix gives me an error saying the functions aren't found:

```
"export 'Func1' (imported as 'Api') was not found in '@/api/api' ....
```

I know the pathing is correct, because for example if I directly import the libs in my view it works:

(vue):

```
<script>
    import Lib1 from '@/api/lib1'
    import Lib2 from '@/api/lib2'
    import Lib3 from '@/api/lib3'

    mounted() {
      Lib1.func1();

      ...

    }

</script>
```

What gives here? I just want a "master" file to import all my Api functions instead of importing each separately.

Some other notes on the environment: I am using Laraval 6 and Vue.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to combine modules, i created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-7eghhx?file=api%2Fapi.js) to show you how it can be done.
Your approach isn't working because you exported `default` and when you are trying to `import './lib1';` name for such module it is just unknown.
Also `import * as Api` will work only if you have several `named` exports but not one `default`.
As i can see you want to combine multiple libraries to one exported object.
There are several methods to achieve your goal:

1. Export named functions only (my favourite):

lib1

```
export function Func1() {
  return ...;
}
export function Func2() {
  return ...;
}
```

then in master file:

```
import * as lib1 from './lib1';

export default {
...lib1
}
```

2. Export default as in your example

lib1

```
export default {
 Func1() {},
 Func2() {}
}
```

then in master file:

```
import lib1 from './lib1';

export default {
...lib1
}
```

3. Export default but combined

lib1

```
export default {
 Func1() {},
 Func2() {}
}
```

then in master file:

```
import lib1 from './lib1';

export default {
 lib1
}
```

but then in your other files you should use it like:

```
import Api from '@api/api';

Api.lib1.Func1()
```

Note: with your current configuration you should use `import Api from '@api/api';` without `*`
Also there is great [article](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2019/01/stop-using-default-exports-javascript-module/) about `named` imports versus `default`.

Answer (score 0):

index.js is where my mind goes automagically. import all of your libs into an index.js in the same directory and export them all from that file. Then you can import them all in a one liner.

index.js

```
import lib1 from './lib1';
import lib2 from './lib2';
import lib3 from './lib3';

export {
  lib1,
  lib2,
  lib3,
};
```

vue

```
import { lib1, lib2, lib3 } from '@/[directory with index.js]';
```

or I think the following would also work and would be used like:

```
import libs from '@/[directory with index.js]';

libs.lib1.someFunction();
```